# PHP ini_set max_execution_time and memory_limit not working

Tags: php, php-5.3

I have the following code inside a file (I'm running it directly via Terminal or I access the webpage, it makes no difference).

```
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
ini_set('display_errors', true);
ini_set('max_execution_time', 1);
ini_set('memory_limit', '512M');
sleep(2);
echo ini_get('max_execution_time');
```

And it outputs `1`. Should it not throw an error, saying that the execution time was excedeed?

From `phpinfo()` I get:

```
max_execution_time  1   55
memory_limit    512M    1024M
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sleep() time does not count toward execution time because it is not executing any code while it is sleeping.

> Note:
>
> The set_time_limit() function and the configuration directive
>   max_execution_time only affect the execution time of the script
>   itself. Any time spent on activity that happens outside the execution
>   of the script such as system calls using system(), stream operations,
>   database queries, etc. is not included when determining the maximum
>   time that the script has been running. This is not true on Windows
>   where the measured time is real.

This includes sleep(), as is mentioned several times in the comments for both sleep() and for set_time_limit(), e.g.

> riki151205-Jun-2007 05:29
>
> Please note that, under Linux, sleeping
>   time is ignored, but under Windows, it counts as execution time.

Comment: wow! thanks a lot! actually I was using a `system()` command that I saw was taking way too long and was wondering why the script wasn't stopped. Any idea if the memory_limit influences the `system()` command?

Comment: If you're using the second argument to exec(), then it's retrieving each line of output from the executed command to that array, so it will use PHP memory